# Resampling a pandas df to graph a financial OLHC chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have a dataframe df that contains an irregular time series that has over 1000 records for a single day, and looks more or less like this:

```
2014-05-10 00:07:04    10
2014-05-10 00:07:48   -20
2014-05-10 00:07:51   -30
2014-05-10 00:09:28    70
2014-05-10 00:09:59    80
2014-05-10 00:10:05     0
2014-05-10 00:10:11    80
2014-05-10 00:10:22    40
2014-05-10 00:11:12    10
2014-05-10 00:12:44    80
2014-05-10 00:12:59    80
2014-05-10 00:13:15    80
2014-05-10 00:16:20    40
```

I am resampling the dataframe like this:

```
ticks = df.ix[:, ['price']]
tick_bars = ticks.price.resample('15min', how='ohlc')
```

Which produces something like this:

```
    open    high    low close
Timestamp               
2014-05-10 00:00:00  10  80 -30  80
2014-05-10 00:15:00  40  80 -30  10
2014-05-10 00:30:00  10  80 -30  70
2014-05-10 00:45:00  0   80 -30  70
2014-05-10 01:00:00  70  70  20  40
2014-05-10 01:15:00  70  80 -20  0
```

After doing this:

```
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick
```

I try to plot the OHLC chart by doing this:

```
candlestick(tick_bars)
```

Obtaining this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-26a465709cae> in <module>()
----> 1 candlestick(tick_bars)

TypeError: candlestick() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

tick_bars already contains the OLHC data, plus the time stamp for the x axis. I am not proficient with matplotlib, so I don't know what argument is missing.

My questions are:

1) What's the missing argument?
2) How can I confine the plotting to a specific time frame (for example 11AM to 2PM), instead of plotting the whole series?
3) Is there an alternative to matplotlib to plot OHLC charts?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `help(candlestick)`?  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/finance.py#L822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and asking some friends, this is what sort of worked for me:

```
tick_bars['t'] = tick_bars.index.map(dates.date2num)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
candlestick(ax, tick_bars[['t', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low']].values, width=1.0 / 3600 * 24)
ax.xaxis_date()
```

Obtaining this chart (needs some styling)
[image]

For an unknown reason, the index (time) needs to be transformed into a decimal number. The chart may look "strange" because I used random data generated from an uniform distribution, with some obvious caps and floors. Also, the scaling needs to be done manually...

Need to find a better library to plot OHLC charts.

Answer (score 0):

The result of a resample places the time as the index of the dataframe. When this happens, calling a mpl function on the df does not pass the index. You can see thus if you type tick_bars.values.  you won't see the time.

Try

```
tick_bars.reset_index(inplace = True)
candlestick(ax,tick_bars.values)
```

This explicitly passes the time.

Comment: I think you mean candlestick(tick_bars.index,tick_bars) right? I tried that and I get ValueError: need more than 4 values to unpack

Comment: Edited answer to make it conform to candlestick syntax.  The root cause is the fact that you need to push the time out of the dataframe index...those are not passed to functions like candlestick.

Comment: edited to reflect axis passing as indicated in docs.  The argument issue you're having doesn't seem to be with pandas but rather with mpl and the axis passing.

Comment: Wrong again. Are you guessing?

Comment: The above works for me with your data.  And the answer you self posted is basically identical...so not sure why the above doesn't work for you.

Comment: THIS: tick_bars['t'] = tick_bars.index.map(dates.date2num) IS NOT the same as this: tick_bars.reset_index(in place = True). Also, you say (in place = True)...you are obviously guessing...do you mean inplace = True? Check your code.